# Append a QVector in a QList

Tags: c++, qt

I want to [append](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#append) a `QVector` in a `QList` but the `QVector` does not append. The size does not change. I try this with:

```
y.value(i).append(var);
```

Variable `y` is declared as `QList<QVector<double>> y;`.

Comment: `y[i].append(var);`, `value` gives you a copy which is immediately destroyed at `;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QList::value()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#value) returns a copy of the element at the given index, not a reference, so modifying it has no effect. Try [operator[]](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#operator-5b-5d) instead.